# HTML tab error notification -- but no error?

Tags: netbeans

This isn't much of a problem, more of an irritant.  I have an HTML file in my project.  The tab shows an error:

[image]

However, there is no error shown in the body of the HTML file.

I don't want to turn off HTML error notifications.  How do I either A) find the error that it thinks exists, or B) get rid of the error notification on the tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open Window->Action Items, maybe there is something.

Comment: And that was EXACTLY where it showed it:  <td style=width:8%%; text-align: right;">  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

if we could see all of that test.html file, did u forget to close any tag maybe? we may could help you out a bit better, have you restart your editor, my editors are having the same issue sometimes... (im using Notepad++)

Comment: I checked all of the tags, and even ran it through an online validator.  No unclosed tags.

Comment: Also restarted it.  Tried copying the text to another file, thinking it was just a Netbeans burp, but the new file did the same thing.

Comment: i dont know netbeans, maybe theres a errorlog? or something like this... a rownumber would be nice or maybe just use the browserdebugger (developertools)